# How to use a list of records

Tags: delphi

I have a record in a method as a local variable. Then I add it to a TList that is a member of the class. Now my question is after the method is finished, is the record is still valid? (or its destroyed and I shouldn't use MyList.List[0]).
this is a sample code:

```
TTestClass = class
  MyList: TList<TMyRec>;
  procedure add;
end;

procedure TTestClass.add;
var
  ARec: TMyRec;
begin
  Arec.a:= 100;
  ARec.b:= 'abc';

  MyList.add(ARec);
end;
```

Comment: records are value types you are safe to use it this way, just remember not to pass it by reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is the record is still valid?

**No**, but its *value* is.

Records are value types allocated on the stack, which means they are passed by value (copied on each assignment)

When you use them as you did, you are actually preforming an implicit copy from your local variable to the storage in the list.

So no, the record declared in the `var` block is not valid when the method finishes execution. But its value is already copied to the storage of the list and therefore it is a valid value.

Consider the following code for more illustration:

```
program Project20;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils, system.generics.collections;

type
  PMyRec = ^TMyRec;
  TMyRec = record
    a: Integer;
    b: string;
  end;

  TTestClass = class
    MyListOfPointers: TList<PMyRec>;
    MyListOfValues: TList<TMyRec>;

    constructor Create;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    procedure add;
    procedure addP;
    procedure ShowRecs;
  end;


  procedure TTestClass.add;
  var
    ARec: TMyRec;
  begin
    Arec.a:= 100;
    ARec.b:= 'abc';

    MyListOfValues.add(ARec);
  end;

  procedure TTestClass.addP;
  var
    ARec: TMyRec;
  begin
    Arec.a:= 100;
    ARec.b:= 'abc';

    MyListOfPointers.add(@ARec);
  end;

  constructor TTestClass.Create;
  begin
    MyListOfPointers := TList<PMyRec>.Create;
    MyListOfValues := TList<TMyRec>.Create;
  end;

  destructor TTestClass.Destroy;
  begin
    MyListOfPointers.Free;
    MyListOfValues.Free;
    inherited;
  end;

  procedure TTestClass.ShowRecs;
  begin
    writeln(PMyRec(MyListOfPointers[0])^.b + ' ' + PMyRec(MyListOfPointers[0])^.a.ToString);
    writeln(MyListOfValues[0].b + ' ' + MyListOfValues[0].a.ToString);
  end;

var
  MyClass: TTestClass;

begin
  try
    MyClass := TTestClass.Create;
    try
      MyClass.Add;
      MyClass.AddP;
      MyClass.ShowRecs;

    finally
      MyClass.Free;
    end;

    Readln;
  except
    on E: Exception do
    begin
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
      Readln;
    end;
  end;
end.
```

the output is

First attempt

```
39866256
abc 100
```

Second attempt

```
40390544
abc 100
```

You won't get an access violation but rather a unique behavior `a` will take any value on that address and `b` will always be empty (`b = ''`) because it is a managed type.